# Save and load of properties

Tags: ant

i try to write ant task, that do the following(pseudo code):

```
if(property1 == null)
   gets property1 from user input and saves this value(so when next time script will be executed the value must be used)
else
   use value
```

So, with another words, if i run script at the first time it must ask some value and save this value for future
And the main thing it must be used only ANT CORE TASKS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
  <target name="load-properties">
    <property file="test.properties" />
  </target>

  <target name="ask-user" unless="my-property" >
    <input
       message="Please provide property"
       addproperty="my-property" />
     <echo file="test.properties" message="my-property=${my-property}" />
  </target>

  <!-- try to load properties-file first, ask user if property is not found -->
  <target name="main" depends="load-properties, ask-user">
    <echo>${my-property}</echo>
  </target>
```